# A problem in Updation of the record c#

Tags: c#, sql

i don't know why every time i perform update of my record, the query from which i update do not increments the ID from 0 to 1 and always it takes 0.. i don't know how do i increment my id to 1 and so far.. please explain.. :/ .. my code is :

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int CustomerID =0;
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=COMPAQ-PC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;
                Initial Catalog=Gym;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("Update Customer set Customer_Name = '" + tbName.Text + "',Cell_Number = '" + tbContactNumber.Text + "',Customer_Address = '" + tbAddress.Text + "' where CustomerID = " + CustomerID, cn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                BindGridView();
            }


private void BindGridView()
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=COMPAQ-PC-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Gym;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Customer", cn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgView_CustomerInfo.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
        }
```

Comment: You are aware that UPDATE updates an *existing* record(s). If ID is an IDENTITY column, it will only increment when you are INSERTing records...

Comment: First and most important thing, read up on SQL Injection and parameterized queries. Second, you're doing something very fishy there...you're binding an empty DataTable to the DataGridView...twice. Which seems rather odd. And third, why should the Id increment, if you never increment it? As far as I see it, you mean the Auto-Id of the table, but an `Update` does not effect it.

Comment: ohh.. i want to update an existing record.. i have initialized  int CustomerID = 0 but.. i am not getting that when a user clicks onto an existing record that is present in the gridview, how will id be changed..

Comment: whether u got a solution for ur problem?

Comment: You can't get an autoincremented value for update operations. You can however get 0 or 1 for ExecuteNonQuery(); which means 0=no records updated, 1= record updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your really need to read a book about .net programming. Your code is full of glitches...

To get you started...

```
        // put the connection string into the app.config
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=COMPAQ-PC-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Gym;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            int result = new SqlCommand("Update Customer set Customer_Name = '" + tbName.Text + "',Cell_Number = '" + tbContactNumber.Text + "',Customer_Address = '" + tbAddress.Text + "' where CustomerID = " + CustomerID, cn).ExecuteNonQuery();
            // eval result to see wether there was realy an updated record...
        }
```

On a `SqlConnection` use the `using()` statement. That way the dispose of the object is taken care of. In fact use it on all objects that are disposable.

Try to use `app.config / web.config` for the connection string.

Escape all the user input that goes to the sql server to prevent sql-injection. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection

Comment: i have replaced my code from your code and it i don't know why it does nothing when i click onto the update button..

Comment: If you set a break-point in the update event, does it actually call the update? And the ID is not incremented in any case since you are updating...

Comment: yes. the Id is not incremented.. my real question was actually about ID, can u please help me how do i increment my ID to 1 or to what the user wants..

Comment: If i were you i'd introduce a second column with the number that the user can set. Try to leave the CustomerID as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Command.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "Update Customer" sql clause.
That means that you are going to update EXISTING record, not to insert NEW one.

The ID is incrementing only for NEW records, but not for existing ones.
Also, make sure that your ID column is properly configured.
It should has IDENTITY(1,1)clause like in example below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[td_Component](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Url] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Caption] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](4000) NULL,
```